# Square number in java

Tags: java

I have to do the method, that I give a number in, if it is a Square number, it will get me true back
if it's not it will get me false back, 
I wrote the code:

```
public class Aufgabe {

    static boolean x;

    public static boolean istQuadratzahl(int zahl){

        int n = (int) Math.sqrt(zahl);
        if (zahl%n == 0){
             x = true;
        }   
        else { 
           return x=false;
        } 

        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){

        System.out.println(istQuadratzahl(6));
    }
}
```

but when I give 6 or 8 in, it gives me true back, where did I go wonge here?

Comment: `return x=false` makes no sense (tip: `x = false` or `return false`)

Comment: Hello Samara92, I'd like to give you a good piece of advice: search before asking, I know you can find an answer to your question on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, sqrt(6) is 2.44948974278. When you cast it to int it becomes 2. Of course, 6 % 2 = 0.
Try to check the result with:

```
if (zahl == n * n){
    x = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
public boolean isSquare(double zahl){
    double m=Math.sqrt(zahl);
    double n=(int)Math.sqrt(zahl);
    if(m==n)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(inputNumber);

 if(sqrt*sqrt == number) {
    System.out.println(number+" is a perfect square number!");
    return true; 
  }else {
    System.out.println(number+" is NOT a perfect square number!");
    return false; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a static variable. In fact, don't use a variable at all.

In addition, your logic is wrong. `(int)Math.sqrt(12) == 3`, `12%3 == 0`, but 12 is not a square.

```
public static boolean istQuadratzahl(int zahl)
{
    int n = (int) Math.sqrt(zahl);

    if (n*n == zahl)
        return true;    
    else 
        return  false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the 'if' to this

```
if (zahl ==  n * n){
```